# For loop and databases in R

Tags: r, database, for-loop

I need to load the nth number of databases for further processing in Rstudio. Is it possible to do this with the for loop?

If do everything with hands (without a loop), it looks like this:

```
d1 = read.spss("r28iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
d2 = read.spss("r27iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
d3 = read.spss("r26iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
```

Realizing that only one digit changes, I create the next vector:

```
c2 = c(9:28)
c2[1]='09'
c3 = c(rep("r",20))
c4 = c(rep("iall_32.sav",20))
g = rev(sort(paste0(c3,c2,c4)))
```

Который принимает значения:

```
[1] "r28iall_32.sav" "r27iall_32.sav" "r26iall_32.sav" "r25iall_32.sav" "r24iall_32.sav" "r23iall_32.sav" "r22iall_32.sav" "r21iall_32.sav"
 [9] "r20iall_32.sav" "r19iall_32.sav" "r18iall_32.sav" "r17iall_32.sav" "r16iall_32.sav" "r15iall_32.sav" "r14iall_32.sav" "r13iall_32.sav"
[17] "r12iall_32.sav" "r11iall_32.sav" "r10iall_32.sav" "r09iall_32.sav"
```

Create a for loop:

```
d = NULL
for (i in (1:20)) {
  d = read.spss(g[i], to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
}
```

and naturally, it returns only the last 20th base. Could you please tell me how to save these databases to the data section each time to get d1,d2,d3 etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the datasets as elements in a list:

```
d = list
for (i in (1:20)) {
  d[[i]] = read.spss(g[i], to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
}
```

Or assign each to a individual variable (but i recommend the first):

```
d = 1:20
for (i in (1:20)) {
  assign(d[i], read.spss(g[i], to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE))
}
```